# Jquery sorting li inside ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

Below is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="ul_s_results">
            <li class="li_results">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="li_name">John</a></td>
                        <td><a class="li_roll">4</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li class="li_results">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="li_name">Jack</a></td>
                        <td><a class="li_roll">1</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li class="li_results">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="li_name">Abe</a></td>
                        <td><a class="li_roll">3</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li class="li_results">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="li_name">Racheal</a></td>
                        <td><a class="li_roll">2</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button>sort</button>
```

I want to sort the list according `class="li_roll"` which is inside a table .
i able to sort the list perfectly if the HTML does not contain `<table>`

**EDIT : it works only if i remove `<table>` tag and `name` e.g.**

```
<li class="li_results">
    <a class="li_roll">4</a>
</li>
```

Anybody know how to sort list while the `li_roll` and `li_name` is inside a table ?

NEW JS CODE:

```
    $(function () {
    var liContents = [];
    $('ul li .li_roll').each (function () {
        liContents.push(parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
        alert($(this).text());
    });

    liContents.sort(numOrdDesc);

    $('ul li').each (function () {
        $(this).text(liContents.pop());
    });
});

function numOrdDesc(a, b){ return (b-a); }
```

result of the js code (it removes all the name )

1

2

3

4

Comment: can you show the javascript you're using to do the sorting?

Comment: Don't sort using `.innerHTML` if that's what you're doing. What value do you want to use for the sort criteria? The name, or the roll?

Comment: @cookiemonster sort criteria is roll number

Comment: Well, you're not actually selecting `"ul li"` are you?

Comment: If you want to sort by the content of a link then why are you sorting by the text of a list item? Why not just add a data-sort-val to the li and avoid deeper elements?

Comment: @cookiemonster js code is while it's working !!! :)

Comment: ```liContents.push(parseInt($(this).find(".li_roll").text(), 10));```

Comment: So you just need to change your selector to grab the  `a` element with the `li_roll` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working sort for your html based on the text value of `.li_roll`

```
$("button").click(function(){
   var lis = $(".li_results");

    lis = lis.sort(function(a,b){
       var num1 = parseInt($(a).find(".li_roll").text(), 10),
           num2 = parseInt($(b).find(".li_roll").text(), 10);
        console.log(num1, num2);
        if (num1 > num2) return 1;
        if (num1 < num2) return -1;
        return 0;
    });

    $(".ul_s_results").html(lis);
});
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f85Ym/